# combine all vectores into dataframe which starts with specific name in R

Tags: r

I have different numeric vectors with the same length and I want to combine those with specific name into dataframe; lets say:
I want to combine vectors which starts with "`pred`"

```
prednn=c(1,2,3,4,5)
prednb=c(2,6,4,7,8)
nope=c(5,7,5,1,1)
predsv=c(55,11,22,33,44)
```

result: `dfpred:`

```
prednn  prednb  predsv
  1       2       55
  2       6       11
  3       4       22
  4       7       33
  5       8       44
```

How can I do it in R?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `mget`

```
data.frame(mget(ls(pattern='^pred')))
#    prednb prednn predsv
#1      2      1     55
#2      6      2     11
#3      4      3     22
#4      7      4     33
#5      8      5     44
```

Comment: @sin `^` means at the beginning of the string and `$` at the end

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `pmatch` in your workplace variables `ls()`.